# VSCode launch flutter emulator doesn't contain the flutter app

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I'm new to flutter. Previously, I've used `flutter emulators --launch Nexus_5X_API_27` to run my code and it worked, however now when I'm writing the command again the emulator doesn't launch the flutter app as it is not even in the apps list. I tried creating a new project, using another emulator, and wiping the emulator data but none worked. When I use `flutter run` the project is run on Edge browser but I need to use the emulator.

[image: A screenshot after running the command]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved after running

```
$ flutter emulators --launch emulatorID
$ flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you emulator is not saving your last state when you close it. Go to emulator snapshot settings and change it, refer below image.

Or else you can do it while creating new emulator.

[image: Click on three dots on emulator for below screen]

Comment: Unfortunately, the settings doesn't have the "Save quick-boot state on exit" option.

Comment: Open Extended Controls from emulator > Snapsdhots > Settings.
And than select **Yes** option in **Auto-save current state to Quickboot. 
See updated screenshot above**